# Maximum cpu verification time

Tags: transactions, nodes, cpu

Do we know the maximum cpu verification time (or max cpu cycles) required by a tx that fills an entire block?

I get that the game theory of tx fees mitigates this, and that the answer will depend slightly on node version, compiler, processor, etc. But is there a rough way to demonstrate that a huge tx won’t take 24 hours to verify?